# R Shiny: Edit a column using a modal popup

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, shiny, popup

I would like to be able to edit only one column in a datatable using a modal with a select input. I want the selected value in the modal to be saved in the table (and be maintained when the user changes page in the datatable). Is there any way to do that in shiny? Here's is a reproducible example, with what I have done so far.
Thanks in advance:)

```
library("shiny")
library("datasets")
library("DT")
library("shinyBS")

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  verbatimTextOutput("selections"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsTable"),
  bsModal("mtCarsModal", "My Modal", "",  htmlOutput("my_numbers"), 
          actionButton("save_changes","Save changes"), size = "small")
))

on_click_js = "
Shiny.onInputChange('mydata', '%s');
$('#mtCarsModal').modal('show')
"

convert_to_link = function(x) {
  as.character(tags$a(href = "#", onclick = sprintf(on_click_js,x), x))
}

shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    output$my_numbers <- renderUI({
      selectInput("my_numbers", "", c(1,2,3,4,5,input$mydata ), selected=input$mydata) 
    })

    mtcarsLinked <- reactive({   
      mtcars$mpg <- sapply(
        datasets::mtcars$mpg,convert_to_link)
      return(mtcars)
    })

    output$mtcarsTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(mtcarsLinked(), 
                    class = 'compact',
                    escape = FALSE, selection='multiple'
      )
    })

    output$selections <- renderText(input$my_numbers)

  }
)
```

Comment: See [DT 0.4: Editing Tables](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/03/29/dt-0-4/)

Comment: Maybe [DTedit](https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit) suits your need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem with DTedit is that it works correctly only for single row selection, while I want multiple row selection for further processing.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the select input. Why don't use an editable table ?